# How is there a 100% chance of finding a hole in the conduction band?

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, probability, electronic-band-theory

[image]

I understand the graph of $f(E)$, but I can't understand the graph of holes $1-f(E)$.

I know that a hole is a concept that represents an electron escaped from the valence band. This means that the holes must be in the valence band.

It is self-evident that electrons and holes are complementary, but is it possible that the probability of finding a hole in the conduction band is 1?

Also, isn't the graph of $1-f(E)$ (i.e., the graph of holes) valid only in the valence band (because holes are found in the valence band)?

Answer (score 3):

**Holes**
Holes are not particles by themselves, but vacancies in otherwise filled valence band. Therefore the concept of a hole is meaningless when talking about a nearly empty band (such as the conduction band of a semiconductor).

**Fermi function**
Fermi function is a function
$$
f(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon-\epsilon_F)}+1},$$
defined for every value of $\epsilon$ in the range $(-\infty, +\infty)$, so there is nothing wrong with plotting it in this range. The same applies to function $1-f(\epsilon)$.

**Filled and empty states**
In the context of the graph in the OP, $f(\epsilon)$ and $1-f(\epsilon)$ are the probabilities of a state of energy $\epsilon$ to be filled with an electron or to be empty. Clearly, most of the states below the Fermi level are filled, while most the states in the conduction band are empty.